# Returning std::string via ternary operator - returns garbage

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, conditional-operator

I'm having the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

std::string name = "Ternary Return Test";
std::string *pname = &name;

const std::string &getName ()
{
    return pname ? *pname : "(unnamed)";
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const std::string &str = getName();
    printf ("Name is \"%s\"\n",str.c_str());
    printf ("pName is \"%s\"\n",pname->c_str());
    return 0; 
}
```

The function getName() dereferences the pname pointer and returns it's value as a reference.
As I understand, returning reference to something, through dereferencing of a pointer is perfectly valid.
In order to avoid NULL pointer dereferencing, the function returns the string "unnamed", in the (in this situation impossible) case, when the pname pointer is NULL.

However, the ternary operator breaks the function. The code compiles, but prints following:

```
Name is "�
          @"
pName is "Ternary Return Test"
```

The value, obtained through the function is broken. I cannot understand why.
In other situation, similar code produces segmentation fault. So, an undefined behaviour is happening here?

Yes, in the case when the pname would be NULL, it would return a reference to temporary, which is undefined. But this is not the case - I am returning a reference to a non-temporary value, which should be perfectly valid.

As I read, the ternary operator converts the third expression "(unnamed)" to the type of the second (std::string). But in my case, the third expression is not even used.

Comment: If you just return `*pname` (no ternary), is everything okay?

Comment: If you're not getting a compile warning on this, turn up your warning level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ternary operator type for

`pname ? *pname : "(unnamed)"` is `std::string` (we have `std::string&` and `const char*`)

So it is equivalent to `pname ? std::string{*pname} : std::string{"(unnamed)"}`.

So you return reference from temporary variable (**in both cases**) (and so dangling reference, leading to UB when you use it).

If you have used `if` instead of ternary, you would have your expected error

```
const std::string& getName()
{
    if pname { return *pname; } // OK here
    return "(unnamed)"; // Dangling pointer here
}
```

One solution might be;

```
const std::string &getName ()
{
    static const std::string unnamed = "(unnamed)";
    return pname ? *pname : unnamed;
}
```

So both sides are lvalue, and common type is now `const std::string &` (`std::string &` and `const std::string&`).

Answer (score 4):

> But this is not the case - I am returning a reference to a non-temporary value, which should be perfectly valid.

You would be, but you don't have a non-temporary value anymore.  [[expr.cond]/4.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.cond#4.3) has

> If E2 is a prvalue or if neither of the conversion sequences above can be formed and at least one of the operands has (possibly cv-qualified) class type:
>
> - if T1 and T2 are the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) and T2 is at least as cv-qualified as T1, the target type is T2,

And what that boils down to is that since the third operand is a prvalue, the entire expression is a prvalue which mean you always have undefined behavior as you are always returning a reference to a temporary.

Answer (score 1):

As Yksisarvinen points out, the problem is a lifetime issue. `"(unnamed)"` has static storage duration, but that's not what you return. You return `std::string{"(unnamed)"}`, and a reference to be exact. That unnamed temporary goes away before the function even returns.

Fix:

```
std::string const& getName ()
{
    static const std::string defaultValue = "(unnamed)";
    return pname ? *pname : defaultValue;
}
```

Comment: And issue is also with `*pname` which also turns into `std::string{*pname}` because or ternary operator.

Comment: @Jarod42: Why? Both `*pname` and `defaultValue` are of the same type, and both are glvalues. This is equivalent to `*(pname?pname:&defaultValue)`.

Comment: @walnut: Yeah, `"unnamed"` itself can be used to initialize a `constexpr` default but that didn't solve the real problem. You need a `static const std::string`.

Comment: @walnut: Not enough coffee for a Monday :|

Comment: I talked about OP's case, not the fixed one. We might read your explanation as issue is only when returning `"(unnamed)"` but the other side as similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

For reference (the dangling-reference UB is well described already), this should probably be something like

```
const std::string &getName ()
{
    static const std::string unnamed("unnamed");
    return pname ? *pname : unnamed;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but that last comment does not make sense. What would the bad branch be? `*pname` when `pname==nullptr`? That is safe, by intention. `*pname` is sequenced-after the test of `pname`.

Comment: If returning a reference to temporary is UB, then having a branch that _would_ do that - even if it is never executed - is problematic. I'll have to think of a better way to express it.

Comment: @Useless That is not correct. You are allowed to have UB in a branch as long as it is never executed. The compiler must still assure that a program that never takes the UB branch executes with the defined behavior.